# Self intersection of diagonal divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $\pi: X\rightarrow B_2$ is a smooth elliptic fibration (over complex numbers and $dim_{\mathbb{C}} X=3, dim_{\mathbb{C}}B=2$). All of the fibers are integral. So for a generic point $b\in B_2$, $E_b=\pi^{-1}b$ is a smooth elliptic curve, and for every point inside discriminant $b\in D \subset B_2$, $E_b$ is either nodal or cuspidal.

Consider the natural diagonal divisor in the fiber product $\Delta \subset X \times_{B_2} X$. I use the following trick to compute the self-intersections of $\Delta$, but what I get is a little surprising, and I appreciate if someone tells what part is wrong.

In general, we have the following S.E.S,

$0\rightarrow I_{\Delta}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X \times_{B_2} X}\rightarrow \delta_* \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow 0$,

where $\delta: X\rightarrow X \times_{B_2} X$ is the natural diagonal morphism. Now one can use Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch to compute,

$ch(I_{\Delta})=1-\delta_* td(\frac{X}{B_2})^{-1}$

Now, if we assume $\Delta$ is Cartier, then $I_{\Delta}=\mathcal{O}_{X \times_{B_2} X}(-\Delta)$, and we can expand the Chern character formula written above to find the self-intersection, and the result is the following,

$\Delta^2=-c_1(B_2) \Delta$, and $\Delta^3$, whatever it is (which is just the third order expansion), doesn't satisfy $\Delta^3 = \Delta^2 \cdot \Delta$, i.e.

$\Delta^3 \ne \Delta^2 \cdot \Delta$.

This cannot be true in normal situations. The usual criticism is, probably $\Delta$ is not Cartier, because of the singularities I mentioned at the beginning...

Comment: Indeed, $\Delta$ is not Cartier.